# What order should I evaluate divergence and coordinate transformation if I want to use a different coordinate system?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

I have a vector field in Cartesian coordinates. I need to find its divergence, but I need the divergence to be in *spherical* coordinates. However, the divergence of this field is far easier to calculate in Cartesian coordinates.

Can I calculate the divergence of the vector field in Cartesian coordinates, and then substitute appropriate values to convert the divergence into spherical coordinates? Or do I have to convert the vector field into spherical coordinates first, and *then* calculate the divergence?

Trying both of these methods yielded different (but somewhat similar) results - but this may simply be due to algebraic errors in my conversion, and not errors in the concept itself.

Comment: If you're doing things right, you should get the same answer whether you convert to spherical basis vectors and spherical coordinates first or second.  Perhaps you should post your attempts for both methods, so we can see what the error is?

Comment: In that case, I'm probably doing my conversion wrong or made algebraic errors. I can't post the attempts, unfortunately - they're for an assignment question; while answering the question, I became curious as to whether it was possible to switch the orders of evaluation.